# Terribly Translated Theatre

Tags: knowledge, movies

We've got some real short movie descriptions for sale! Solve them now and win imaginary points! Come one, come all! We'll even let you take home the posters!

1. > A gang of all shapes and sizes decide to take a hike and get real toasty. One of them dies but that's okay... he lives on. I really think there is too much fire... hey! Those trees have a face!
2. > A lot of musical weirdos decide to follow an equally mellifluous guy who turns into an a-hole. But everything's fine! He becomes *not* an a-hole once everything is taken away from him.
3. > The Knights of what? There's a rabbit and some horses- wait no, there's no horses. How gory! Poor guy.
4. > Woah, funky! Foxy! This place is groovin'! A giant ship farts underwater? That's my kind of content right there. Nice pottymouth, dirt bag!

> 1 has been found by: Kevorobin
> 2 has been found by: El-Guest
> 3 has been found by: Rand al'Thor
> 4 has been found by: El-Guest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 1 (Thanks to @kevorobin, go upvote his answer!)

> The Lord of the Rings (You shall not pass!)

Number 2

> The Greatest Showman, where the a'hole is PT Barnum once he hits the big time (and Hugh Jackman is one heck of a singer!)

Number 3 (Thanks to @Rand al'Thor, go upvote his answer!)

> Monty Python and the Holy Grail (Ekke ekke ekke ekke ptang zoom boing!)

Number 4

> Austin Powers [(Groovy, baby!)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY4Ytj0itGo)

Comment: ohohoho yes it indeed could be :) Though my fart referenced a different part of the same movie.

Comment: Nice! Is this okay or should I update for the specific name of the movie @iiiidk?

Comment: That's fine! I had the first one reference a broad series name as well.

Comment: Sounds great! Is this the answer for #2 as well??

Comment: Woah there, you got two of 'em! Guess you win some *more* points.

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeet! Let me consolidate and give credit where it's due!

Answer (score 3):

*Partial answer*

1. > This sounds like a superhero film, but I don't know enough about those to be able to identify it.
2. > This sounds like the Pied Piper of Hamelin.
3. > **Monty Python and the Holy Grail**. Knights of Ni, Killer Rabbit of Caerbannog, coconut-shell 'horses', Black Knight.

Comment: The most iconic was found first :') Fitting!

Comment: As soon as I saw "The Knights of what?" I thought of this :-)

Comment: They're following a creepy guy with a flute, @iiiidk man that's pretty weird

Comment: @iiiidk I was thinking of the rats, actually ... he becomes an a'hole after that.

Comment: [Here's a link to the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pied_Piper_of_Hamelin). Depending on who you ask, he does a lot of different things, some a'holeish, some even more a'holeish.

Answer (score 3):

1. > The Lord of the Rings

The one who is (thought to be) dead but lives on is

> Gandalf

Those trees have a face!

> The Ents from The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers

Comment: There it be! Thine answer holds true!

Comment: [_One_ of them dies???](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/one-does-not-simply-walk-into-mordor)